# ECDSA Android verify with Public Key always return false

Tags: android, android-keystore, ecdsa

I have some token and I need first to sign it with SHA256 and ECDSA based on private and public key from KeyStore.

Every time when I try to verify value I get false as result. I do not know why.

**Does someone have any idea how to solve this?**

Here are my functions to generate and load keys:

```
private void generateKeys(){

    try {

        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
        keyStore.load(null);

        if(!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_NAME)) {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC, KEYSTORE_NAME);
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                    new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                    KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
                            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                            .build());
            keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            setRegistred(true);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



private void loadKeys(){
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
        keyStore.load(null);
        if(keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_NAME)) {
            publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(KEY_NAME).getPublicKey();
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how sign value:

```
 public String sign(String inputStr, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject){
    try {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE);
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        signature.update(inputStr.getBytes());
        byte[] signedBytes = signature.sign();
        String result = Base64.encodeToString(signedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("TAG", result);
        return result;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my try to verify with Public Key:

```
public boolean verifyWithPublicKey(String input, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject){
    try {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE);
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_NAME);
        keyStore.load(null);
        PublicKey pk  = getPublicKeyForVerification();
        signature.initVerify(pk);
        signature.update(input.getBytes());
        boolean isVerifed = signature.verify(input.getBytes());
        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(isVerifed));
        return isVerifed;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is here, when you write the following code to verify the signature:

```
signature.update(input.getBytes());
boolean isVerifed = signature.verify(input.getBytes());
```

With this code, you try to verify that the signature has been signed with itself!

You should have:

```
signature.update(MY_BYTES_ARRAY_OF_DATA);
boolean isVerifed = signature.verify(MY_SIGNATURE);
```

**Do not forget that the signature does not encapsulate the signed data by default.**

If you want to have a format that includes signed data and associated signature, use S/MIME, OpenPGP, etc.